# How to include a php file into two others which are in different directories ? (not the other way around!)

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with the folowing:

I have a file called config.php, which I include in two other pages: login.php and index.php. The pages are organized as follows:

```
           index.php
           Config/config.php
           Page/Users/Login/login.php
           lib/smarty.php
```

My problem, is that, within config.php, I have another include to a different file: smarty.php. 
But because index.php and login.php are not on the same level, the smarty file only works for one of them:

Example : if I have, in config.php:
                                       include('lib/smarty.php')

then it only works for index.php

```
      if I have          include('../../../lib/smarty.php')
```

then it only works for login.php

Is there a way for me to use the same config.php for both login.php and index.php and have smarty.php work for both?

I hope I was clear, and thank you in advance

NOTE: The problem is not how to include files from different folders into another, it is to include one file into two different pages in different directories and with different paths.

Comment: @jeroen , as I explain on my NOTE, my problem is somewhat different from the one you posted, but thank you anyway

Comment: I'm not sure that's a different problem. Anyway, the answer is the same, set something like a base-path for your app or use something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to make sure you always have the correct - complete - path for the file you want to include (instead of a relative path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dirname(__FILE__)`, or if available, `__DIR__` (PHP >= 5.3). They resolve to the full path of the directory the current file is in. It is better than explicitly using the current absolute path to the file because it allows you to move the files in the file system (as long as the files stay in the same location, relative to each other).

You'll have to change `Config/config.php` to include `lib/smarty.php` like so:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/smarty.php');
```

While you're at it, you should probably change your other include/require to use a similar construct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path in all of your includes.

like:

include '/var/www/html/Config/config.php';